# After dismiss the imagePickerController, how to go back to the current tab instead of the default tab

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, swift4

I have 4 tabs in the tab bar. Currently, I am working in the 4th tab, and having an imagePickerController. After the imagePickerController dismissed, it goes to the default tab (1st tab). How can I make it go to the current (4th) tab?

```swift
class EditMyPostViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var postImageView: UIImageView!


    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imagePicker.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func updatePhotoTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add a picture", message: "How do you want to upload the picture?", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: .default, handler: { action in
            self.takePhotoWithCamera()
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Use Existing Photo", style: .default, handler: { action in
            self.getPhotoFromLibrary()
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}

extension EditMyPostViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func takePhotoWithCamera() {
        if (!UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera)) {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "No Camera", message: "The device has no camera.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func getPhotoFromLibrary() {
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
        {
            postImageView.image = image
        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The `imagePicker` is present in the 2 functions `takePhotoWithCamera()` and `getPhotoFromLibrary()`. 
In the last function, I tried to `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`, but it goes to the default tab instead of the current tab. How can I present the current ViewController?

I tried

```swift
present(self, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But it will cause an Exception: Application tried to present modally an active controller

Comment: edit your code to show how you are presenting your `imagePickerController`, and which view controller are you presenting it from?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Thanks, I updated my code. It is presenting from the `EditMyPostViewController`.